# WP json rest api captcha issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using below endpoint in wordpress.

https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3&page=1&insecure=cool

In response its showing `Please enable cookies` `one more step` `Please complete the securuity check to access example.com`. So any rest api i access gives the same error of cors policy and in postman its showing above message.

Its working fine in browser but when running that api in postman or implementing it to ionic it gives the error.

Any help will be appreciated.